# How can I create a text link on a webView to manually

Tags: android, webview

I have a simple `webView` object  and I want create a text link on the `webView` to manually. I do not want to have the text link from a external server. I want create a text link to manually on my `webView`. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "text link on the webView" ??

Comment: [TextLink](http://www.stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XML file:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

 <WebView 
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

In Class onCreate() :

```
    mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);


    mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

You should add a TextView with the text, the text itself doesn't matter, but you have to use an url while coding.

Set onClick and clickable to the Textview:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onTextViewClick"
            android:text="Click this text"  
/>
```

And handle it:

```
TextView mTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
String url = "https://www.google.com"

public void onTextViewClick(View v) {
if(v.getId() == R.id.txtView){
    mWebView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Comment: When I did this, Can I go to the link when I click on the text?

Comment: Yes, I updated my code. But couldn't test it. Sorry. Please give it a try